# Moodle populate multiselect with selected value

Tags: moodle

I am new to `moodle`, what I am trying to do is,

I have made some edit in one of the form class which `moodleform`. Now added a new field to it.

```
$teacherSelect = $mform->createElement('select', 'teachers', "Teachers", $teachers);
$teacherSelect->setMultiple(true);
```

This works fine, when wish to save the data.

But however now I need to set the data, when the form populate. I am not able to understand in which format I should have the data structured so that it can be used to populate the data back to multi-select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the record then add a property with the array of selected items and set the data in the calling code, eg: in edit.php something like

```
$myrecord = $DB->get_record('mytable');
...
// Selected teachers - its a key so you can use either integers or strings.
$myrecord->teachers = array('teacher1','teacher2'); 
...
$mform = new myform();
...
$mform->set_data($myrecord); // This sets the data in the form.
```

For a better example, have a look at categories in the file /mod/glossary/edit.php